# wglMakeCurrent with hdc parameter NULL

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, wgl

According to the registered here ([khronos site](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/WGL_ARB_create_context.txt)):

> If the OpenGL context version of <hglrc> is 3.0 or above, and if
>       either the <hdc> parameter of wglMakeCurrent is NULL, or both of the
>       <hDrawDC> and <hReadDC> parameters of wglMakeContextCurrentARB are
>       NULL, then the context is made current, but with no default
>       framebuffer defined. The effects of having no default framebuffer on
>       the GL are defined in Chapter 4 of the OpenGL 3.0 Specification.

Trusting this information I created a device context "off screen" with:

```
HDC m_hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
```

I configured the Pixels and added to DC with the `SetPixelFormat` function:

```
SetPixelFormat(m_hDC, iPixelFormat, &chosenPFD);
```

Then I created a rendering context:

```
m_hGLRC = ::wglCreateContextAttribsARB(m_hDC, NULL, &(iAttributes[0]));
```

So far so good, it works.
Now it's time to make the context current.

First I delete the DC (I will not need it anymore) and call the `wglMakeCurrent` with a `NULL` `dc` parameter:

```
DeleteDC(m_hDC);
bool ret = wglMakeCurrent(NULL, m_hGLRC);
```

That did not work. The `ret` is `false` and I get this error:

> Win32 Error# (6): ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Comment: Error code 6 is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. Nothing in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374387.aspx) states, that passing `NULL` as the *hdc* parameter were allowed.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for describing the error, edited :). Although the msdn documentation does not state about hdc NULL, the khronos documentation mentions :\

Comment: Can I ask if your window is CS_OWNDC?

Comment: @Robinson: There is no window.

Comment: I don't know, whether Microsoft's implementation supports this use case. If it does, you cannot simply rip the DC from underneath it, though. You have to render *somewhere* after all. You'd probably also have to select a bitmap of sufficient size and with compatible pixel format into the target DC to serve as the backing store.

Comment: @Mano-Wii You need a window to create an OpenGL context (at least a hidden window). See [Creating OpenGL context without window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482166/creating-opengl-context-without-window)

Comment: @Rabbid76, thanks for the info. I'm still confused about the difference between DC and window. Since OpenGL works on framebuffers (not windows) I wanted to avoid then. And it would even be possible if it were not for that DC :\

Comment: @Mano-Wii Please belive me, it is not possible to cretea an OpenGL context (above 1.0) with out an window. You need a `HWND hwnd`, `HDC hdc = ::GetWindowDC( hwnd );` and `::wglCreateContext( hdc )`. See [Render image using OpenGL in win32 window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809267/render-image-using-opengl-in-win32-window/47821419#47821419)

Comment: @Rabbid76, do I really need to get the DC from a window (`::GetWindowDC( hwnd );`)?? If I use the dc from `CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);`, the context works!! I'd rather store this dc somewhere than store a window.

Comment: @Mano-Wii No, becaus if you use a memory context, the you won't get an OpenGL context above OpenGL version 1.0.

Comment: Is the OpenGL context version of <hglrc> 3.0 or above?

Comment: yes, OpenGL 3.3

Comment: @Rabbid76, It seems that the limitation with context above 1.0 only occurs with Intel cards. In my case it worked because I used AMD. Anyway I created the DC with pbuffer. But I did not want to have to create a DC :( (NULL would be perfect)